# ConvertTo-Html wrong output

Tags: powershell

I want to save the output in the following picture to a file using ConvertTo-Html ps command.
[image: Lists and tables of data in a console.]

Here is my command:

```
node index.js -f ..\IT -u 20 -s 0.5 | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File output.htm
```

and this is the output:

[image: A list of numbers that don't appear in the image above.]

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: If you are after an exact html representation of the console output you may be better of with [Get-ConsoleAsHtml.ps1](https://gist.github.com/lazywinadmin)

Comment: That is exactly what I want. Thank you. Can you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are after an exact html representation of the console output,
you may be better off with

[Get-ConsoleAsHtml.ps1](https://gist.github.com/lazywinadmin/101ecf6530b794e3b7a7)

An alternative is

[Console screen grabs in html](https://ps1.soapyfrog.com/2007/01/06/console-screen-grabs-in-html/)

Both copy from `$host.ui.rawui.GetBufferContents($rec)` use a fixed width font and apply colours. So the output can be copied as text from the page and take less space than a picture.